# Tkinter new window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm relatively new to Tkinter and I need help.

I have created a new window when a button is clicked from the parent window. The new window is the def new_Window. But I can't seem to get the information in the window as coded below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



#User Interface Code

root = Tk() #Creates the window
root.title("Quiz Game")

def new_window(): 
    newWindow = Toplevel(root)
   display = Label(newWindow, width=200, height=50)
   message = Label(root, text="Welcome")
   display.pack()
   message.pack()


display2 = Label(root, width=100, height=30)

button1 = Button(root, text ="Continue", command=new_window, width=16, 
bg="red")

message_label = Label(root, text="Click 'Continue' to begin.", 
wraplength=250)

username = StringVar() #Stores the username in text
user_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=username) #Creates an entry for the 
username 
user_entry.pack()
display2.pack()
button1.pack()
message_label.pack()

root.mainloop()#Runs the main window loop
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not pack the hello label into the new window. A tip is also to use background colors to visualize labels when developing. Here is a functioning code for you. I only changed 2 lines, added foreground and background.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



# User Interface Code

root = Tk() # Creates the window
root.title("Quiz Game")

def new_window(): 
   newWindow = Toplevel(root)
   display = Label(newWindow, width=200, height=50,bg='RED')
   message = Label(newWindow, text="HEEEY",fg='BLACK',bg='GREEN')
   message.pack()
   display.pack()


display2 = Label(root, width=100, height=30)

button1 = Button(root, text ="Continue", command=new_window, width=16, 
bg="red")

message_label = Label(root, text="Click 'Continue' to begin.", 
wraplength=250)

username = StringVar() # Stores the username in text
user_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=username) # Creates an entry for the 
username 
user_entry.pack()
display2.pack()
button1.pack()
message_label.pack()

root.mainloop() # Runs the main window loop
```